# https link showing in outlook where preview should be

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, thunderbird

One of my customers mentioned to me that the way they have out look set up, allows them to see a short email preview in the form

```
hello@email.com
Hi, this is a message preview
```

However when I email, the get a big long https string and at first they thought that the email might include a virus so were dubious about opening it.
I am keen to find a way to stop this happening.

My email displays as

```
me@email.com
<https://z86orge6w04.....>
```

I use Thunderbird to send my emails, I shouldnt think that my email client would cause this though.

Also I use an smtp relay `mailersend` and their details are included in the https link as you will see from the pic.

I have also used socket labs and when I send using their relay, the link is still there but changes slightly
So I think that it may be something to do with the fact I use an SMTP relay

I have noticed though that it only seems to be outlook that shows this, Gmail, thunderbird and others that I have sent testemails to do not display in this manner.

At first I thought that it was because my logo in the header contained a link to the website but I have removed the link and there is no change

The part at the top circled in yellow is what they see when I email, the bit below circled in red is what they see from everyone else

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related with Thunderbird but with [MailerSend](https://www.mailersend.com/) which is a transactional email service.

According to [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/en-gb/marketing-glossary/transactional-email/):

> Transactional emails are automated emails sent from one sender to one recipient, usually related to account activity or a commercial transaction.

The URL shown in the Outlook preview is a tracking URL. You can solve this problem by removing tracking or by asking support to MailerSend.